# How to download excel files in fastify?

Tags: fastify

[This is my API response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0UTe7.jpg) Currently, I'm using "node-excel-export" package for downloading. It is converted to excel format but the download functionality is not working. Here is my code

```
     var specification = {
        ASSIGNED_TO: {
            displayName: 'ASSIGNED_TO',
            width: '10',
            headerStyle: { font: { bold: true } }
        },
     };

    var fileName = 'Parent-List';
    var sheetData = {
        name: 'Sheet 1',
        specification: specification,
        data: responseData
    };
    var report = excel.buildExport([sheetData]);
    reply.header('Content-Type', 'application/vnd.openxmlformats');
    reply.header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + fileName + '.xlsx');
    
    reply.send(report);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Do you have any stacktrace?

Comment: Do you mean sending the Excel to browser?

Comment: from the front-end, I had just done only one button click for this API call. after that, I have used the node-excel-export package for downloading. 

Actually, I converted my array of data to excel and then need to download it. But I couldn't get any downloaded excel from my browser. I attached my API response in the top.

Comment: Seems like headers are specified correctly, so I guess the problem might be with data type of your report, what is it exactly?

Comment: Another possible issue is the way you are calling your "download" endpoint from the client, in browsers the easiest and most straight forward way would be to create a download link using <a> tag https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_html_download_link.asp that will just call your endpoint.